# Display integers in sequential order from smallest to largest in java

Tags: java

Have the user enter 4 positive integers.  Display these integers in sequential order from the smallest to the largest.  For example, if the user enters 4, 14, 2, 7, then you should display 2, 4, 7, 14. this is in java.

```
package module3p8;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class M3E8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String num1Response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any postive integer?");
        int number1 = Integer.parseInt(num1Response);

        String num2Response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any postive integer?");
        int number2 = Integer.parseInt(num2Response);

        String num3Response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any postive integer?");
        int number3 = Integer.parseInt(num1Response);

        String num4Response = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any postive integer?");
        int number4 = Integer.parseInt(num4Response);

        if (number1 < number2 && number1 < number3 && number1 < number4 && number2 < number3 && number2 < number4 && number3 < number4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number1 + number2 + number3 + number4);
        } else if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3 && number1 > number4 && number2 > number3 && number2 > number4 && number3 > number4) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, number4 + number3 + number2 + number1);
        } else if (number1 > number2 && number1 > number3 && number1 > number4 && number2 > number3 && number2 > number4 && number3 > number4) {
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:  This is homework-related.

Comment: Can you describe some things you tried, or some of the problems you are having (with code)?  The purpose of this website is not for the community to do work for you, but to guide you with specific issues you are facing.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is this your homework? Please at least make an attempt  and post code -- that's what this site is for.

Comment: It looks like you haven't put in any work at all and just want us to do your work for you.  Please demonstrate that you have put in an effort and give a specific question about how we can help you.

Comment: Am i on the right track?

Comment: What happens when you run your code? This part intrigues me: `number4 + number3 + number2 + number1`. Remember, you're now adding numbers, not concatenating Strings.

Comment: well, not really. have a look at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm) if you want to implement the sorting yourself.

Comment: You aren't really on the right track.  Here's a hint: instead of checking the combinations of the numbers (seeing if num1 is bigger than num2 etc), you might want to think about creating an array of four numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is homework, I'll only give hints, and not a full solution.

Instead of checking all possibilities of which to print first, you might want to store all data, sort it - and then print it.

Have a look at [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29)

or use an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) and look at [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28long%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [Collection.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) method.

Here is a code snippet of what you have to achieve.

```
ArrayList<Integer> number = new ArrayList<Integer>();

while(number.size()<4)
number.add (phone_number);

Collections.sort(number);
```

Comment: I am using while loop because i supposed user giving input from terminal.

Answer (score 2):

To impress, you can use a data structure that keeps its contents sorted as they are inserted, ala [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

**Reference**

- [Java user input tutorial](http://www.landofcode.com/java-tutorials/java-user-input.php)
- [Priority Queues<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue)